# Access to ServletContext in Jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I'm advancing in jee programming. From basic tutorials if I want read my application directory in class extending HttpServlet I use getServletContext().getRealPath(relativePath). But In my case I used Jersey for serialization purposes. Servlet not extending HttpServlet, look at image[image] . I'm mainly front programmer so maybe it is stupid question, but I want simple static/util method for resolving pathes to different static resources in my webapp. I run it on Tomcat. One and only servlet as on image.

Answer (score 2):

As per specs (JAX-RS 1.1, ch. 6.1), add this in your resource class:

```
@Context
private ServletContext application;
```

The fully quallified names are:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
```

Comment: Context bindinding is manged by container so if I tried use it servlet constructor or static method context was null.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path to your `webApp/WEB-INF/classes` directory can be accessed as below:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/");
String path = resource.getPath();
```

This will return you an absolute path like this:

```
/C:/SERVERS/x/y/x/yourApp/WEB-INF/classes
```

And from this you can get the path to the webapp directory:

```
path = path.replace("WEB-INF/classes/", "");
```

Now if your static resource is directly under `webapp`, you can access that resource with this:

```
path = path + "resource_name";
```

Comment: Looks simple and right. I will try it later. Now I found that my ressource must be outside webapp direcoty.